# How to handle agent moves through nested list with x and y co-ordinates

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on the A star algorithm and I need some help regarding the movement of my agent. My A star functions gives me a path of x,y co-ordinates in a nested list to the closest goal. I need to move my agent through that path to reach the closest goal.

I've tried using the `range(len(path) -1)` in the `for` loop but it only spits out one move while the game has to run on 100 iterations. I'm working on the function `def gather_closest_goal`. The first element of the nested list is the position of my agent and the last element of the list is the closest goal.

```
def gather_closest_goal(self,field,figure,path):
    figure_position = self.get_player_position(figure,field)

    for i in range(len(path)-1):
        if (path[i][0] == path[i+1][0] -1) and (path[i][1] == path[i[1]):
            return MOVE_RIGHT
    for i in range(len(path) - 1):
        if (path[i][0] == path[i+1][0]) and (path[i][1] == path[i+1][1]+1):
            return MOVE_UP
        if (path[i][0] == path[i+1][0]) and (path[i][1] == path[i+1][1]-1):
            return MOVE_UP
        if (path[i][0] == path[i+1][0]) and (path[i][1] == path[i-1][1] +1):
            return MOVE_DOWN
        else:
            return MOVE_LEFT

def move_sheep(self,player_number,field):
    if player_number == 1:
        figure = CELL_SHEEP_1
        sheep_position = tuple(self.get_player_position(CELL_SHEEP_1, field))
    else:
        figure = CELL_SHEEP_2
        sheep_position = tuple(self.get_player_position(CELL_SHEEP_2, field))

    if self.wolf_close(player_number,field):
        #print('wolf close move')
        return self.run_from_wolf(player_number,field)
    if self.food_present(field):
        #print('gather food move')
        # print(astar(field,sheep_position,(2,5)))
        return self.gather_closest_goal(field,figure,astar(field,sheep_position,self.closest_goal(player_number,field)))
    else:
        return MOVE_NONE
```